# Android popupMenu for earlier version

Tags: android

What I want to do is I want to use **PopupMenu** when device is later ICS, for earlier version, it will automatically change to **contextmenu**.

It can be controlled by code?

Comment: So did you try something so far?

Comment: have not yet. That's why asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check which Android version is currently using the device

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
       //show context menu as you need
} else {
       // show pop up
}
```